nginx configuration that permits removing index.php from urls and passing pathinfo to index.php scripts but not other php scripts
I don't have much experience with nginx (though I have a lot with apache and web services in general.)
My requirements are below. I have not yet managed to cobble together a config that meets them all. I've done my due RTFMing, googling, and playing around of course, and I've figured out some different ways to meet some but not all of them. I'm hesitant to trial and error it all out anyway because I don't know enough about nginx to be able to assess the quality of any solution I might come up with.
Some of the specific issues I've had include getting PATH_INFO when the url explicitly contained index.php but not otherwise, the request being handled by /index.php when that exists but I want it to be handled by a more deeply nested one like /foo/index.php, and a script handling a request where the path_info includes an existing dir but ends with a non-existent subdir or file (a case where I want a 404.) This is not a comprehensive list of the issues I've run into.
I'd be most grateful for a complete solution, but any answers that get me closer will be appreciated.
Example website directory:
…/assets/css/site.css
…/index.php
…/gallery/index.php
…/script.php 


Directory indexes will include index.php and index.html.
If an index.php script handles a request but isn’t explicit in the URL, it should get pathinfo.

https://example.com/foo/bar should be handled by …/index.php and receive “/foo/bar” as pathinfo.


Only index.php files should get pathinfo; other php scripts should not.

https://example.com/script.php/foo/bar should 404.


If index.php is explicit in the URL, it should not execute.

https://example.com/index.php/foo/bar should 404.


If the URL includes multiple directories that each contain an index.php then the last one should be the script that handles the request.

https://example.com/gallery/foo/bar should be handled by …/gallery/index.php and it should get /foo/bar as pathinfo.


A request for a URL containing a directory that actually exists but does not have its own index.php should not be handled by a script at all.

https://example.com/assets/css should not be handled by …/index.php; it should 404 because it exists but has no index.
https://example.com/assets/foo should not be handled by …/index.php; it should 404 because …/assets exists but has no index.



